# Gtk-Python : Is it possible to print a window content and how to do this?

Tags: python, printing, gtk

I have a Gtk.Window which contains a Gtk.Grid and Gtk.Labels.
I would like to print all of what is displayed on this window. Is it possible to do this and how?

I've searched for tutorials but only found one to print pdf files.

Here is my print function :

```
def on_print(self, widget):
    print("*** Print ***")
    print_op = Gtk.PrintOperation()
    print_op.set_n_pages(1)
    print_op.connect("draw_page", self.print_window)
    res = print_op.run(Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT_DIALOG, None)

def print_window(self):
```

Could you tell me what should I code in the "print_window" callback function, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880235/how-to-capture-image-of-a-gtk-applicationwindow-in-python-in-linux.

Comment: Hello @theGtknerd. I've tried the solution you linked but it saves all the window content, the window itself included. I would like to get an image of only the Gtk.Grid, without window frame (grid of example, but it could be any other widget the window is containing)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have reworked the example I linked in my comment. This should only grab the box inside the window.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import cairo
import sys


class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Welcome to GNOME")
        self.set_default_size(200, 100)
        self.image_file = image_file="/home/house/window.png"
        self.vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        self.add(self.vbox)
        label = Gtk.Label()
        label.set_text("Hello GNOME!")
        self.vbox.pack_start(label, True, True, 0)
        self.button = Gtk.Button("ScreenshotMe!")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_save_image)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.button, False, False, 0)
        self.show_all()
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

    def on_save_image(self, button):
        """
        Get the surface of the current window and save it as a png
        """
        window = self.get_window()
        width, height = self.vbox.get_allocated_width(), \
                        self.vbox.get_allocated_height()
        surface = Gdk.Window.create_similar_surface(window,
                                                    cairo.CONTENT_COLOR,
                                                    width, height)
        cairo_context = cairo.Context(surface)
        Gdk.cairo_set_source_window(cairo_context, window, 0, 0)
        cairo_context.paint()
        surface.write_to_png(self.image_file)

def main():
    app = MyWindow()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Thank you @theGtknerd. I've tried this code. Actually, the surface to print include only the vbox and the button. This is better, but I would like to print only the vbox. Isn't there a way to select only the vbox widget or to select a surface with x,y,height & width? I've checked Cairo functions and saw there are gdk_cairo_draw_from_gl (), gdk_cairo_rectangle () and gdk_cairo_region () methods. But I don't know if those would do the trick and don't know how to use them. No example found about it.

Comment: At least, I found a simple example with rectangle() method on this page : https://askubuntu.com/questions/220350/how-to-add-a-print-dialog-to-an-application I'll see what I can do with it.

Comment: Or, you could rearrange the widgets and have another grid within the vbox, then only grab the area of the grid.