# how can print my window , using glade gtk python

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, glade

i'm actually creating a little software with glade and gtk in python ,

this software is used to see the stock of some product , i'm trying to print my entire window , 
after looking for some solution, the first step will be probably to screenshot and save the entire window , and after print this one

i've seen tat [Gtk-Python : Is it possible to print a window content and how to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53646008/gtk-python-is-it-possible-to-print-a-window-content-and-how-to-do-this)

but i'm using glade , so my object are already define into a .glade file so i don't really know how to adapt that

i'm new using gtk / glade

```
def when_button_is_clicked5(label):
"
is there i'm supposed to screen and save the window
but i've no idea how to do that with a glade file ...
"

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file('inv/inv.glade')
window = builder.get_object('window2')
window.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
handler = {'on_button1_clicked': when_button_is_clicked1,
....'on_button10_clicked': when_button_is_clicked10 }
builder.connect_signals(handler)
labelhisto = builder.get_object('labelhisto')
....
labelgame20 = builder.get_object('labelgame20')
list1 = builder.get_object('list1')
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).